# Could not find icon {prefix: 'fab', iconName: 'spotify'}

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to show some icon on my footer but it isn't showing up . throwing me the following error

**Could not find icon {prefix: 'fab', iconName: 'spotify'}**

main code :

```
const Footer = () => {
return (
    <div className='bg-primary'>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-brands fa-facebook" />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-brands fa-youtube" />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-brands fa-spotify" />
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: please share the package.json.

Comment: package.json :: 
https://codeshare.io/X8wVDM

Comment: Did you check that it is a free icon that you want (or available to you otherwise)? Also, have you checked the font awesome library version you're using versus the version you're getting this icon from?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to resolve this, but mainly it is stated in the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons). I assume you've already done the setup to use the FontAwesome icon from the package. From the codes of what you are trying to do, looks like you want to use the icon globally. However, I find it easier if I import it individually like this :

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const Footer = () => {
return (
    <div className='bg-primary'>
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
    </div>
);
```

Again, this is my preference because I find it easier, if you look for adding it globally try to add it first to the `library` as stated in the documentation.

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faTwitter, faFontAwesome } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(fas, faTwitter, faFontAwesome)

const Footer = () => {
return (
    <div className='bg-primary'>
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-twitter" />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: if you find this is the right answer, don't forget to check this as the right answer. It will help the other people with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For brand icons, you just need to install `@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons`

and then:

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faFacebookF, faYoutube, faSpotify} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

const Footer = () => {
return (
    <div className='bg-primary'>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSpotify} />
    </div>
);
```