# How to import font awesome icons in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, font-awesome

Having installed in package.json the following dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "~6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "~6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "~6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "~6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "~6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "~6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "~6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-thin-svg-icons": "~6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    ...
```

In order to use some icons in the project it is used the following approach:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {
  faBookOpen,
  faBriefcase,
  faBrowser,
} from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons';


...

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBookOpen} />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBriefcase} />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBrowser} />
```

This works fine. But there are some icons that aren't in `@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons` but they are available [here](https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/twitter?s=solid&f=brands).

In order to use the twitter icon I've tried to do it like:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fab fa-twitter" />
```

It generates the error:

```
Type '"fab fa-twitter"' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(24, 3): The expected type comes from property 'icon' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FontAwesomeIconProps'
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: did you try `import { faTwitter, faFontAwesome } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'` `library.add(fas, faTwitter, faFontAwesome)
` `<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-twitter" />` ?
described hree https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73440173/could-not-find-icon-prefix-fab-iconname-spotify